# Extension method with dynamic named parameters

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods

I'm currently writing an extension to *replace* the normal `string.Format` with my `FormatNamed`-function.

So far I have got this code, but I want to change the way to input the parameters

```
void Main()
{
    string sql = "SELECT {fields} FROM {table} WHERE {query}"
        .FormatNamed(new { fields = "test", table = "testTable", query = "1 = 1" });
    Console.WriteLine(sql);
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string FormatNamed(this string formatString, dynamic parameters)
    {
        var t = parameters.GetType();
        var tmpVal = formatString;
        foreach(var p in t.GetProperties())
        {
            tmpVal = tmpVal.Replace("{" + p.Name + "}", p.GetValue(parameters));
        }
        return tmpVal;
    }
}
```

Not the prettiest of replaces, but it does the job.

Anyway. I want to change so I can execute it with

```
.FormatName(field: "test", table: "testTable", query: "1 = 1");
```

Is there any way I can do this? I have tried googling for dynamic named parameters with no good results.

Comment: Use sql-parameters to parametrize your sql queries, don't format the sql string yourself by concatenating all fields and values together. You are open for sql-injectionn attacks.

Comment: @TimSchmelter We have code to sanitize the SQL's, but I didn't include them here, I just needed an example-string. And SQL was the first I could think of. :)

Comment: Yeah, should've gone with an translation-example. ^^ `string phrase = "{item} will cost about {cost} in the {storeName}-store".Forma...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to specify an arbitrary number of dynamic, named parameters. that's just not something that C# supports. Your existing code seems okay to me, although I don't see the need for the `dynamic` parameter. This will work just as well:

```
public static string FormatNamed(this string formatString, object parameters)
{
    var t = parameters.GetType();
    var tmpVal = formatString;
    foreach(var p in t.GetProperties())
    {
        tmpVal = tmpVal.Replace("{" + p.Name + "}", p.GetValue(parameters));
    }
    return tmpVal;
}
```

And then calling it as:

```
string sql = "SELECT {fields} FROM {table} WHERE {query}"
    .FormatNamed(new { fields = "test", table = "testTable", query = "1 = 1" });
```

Although I really wouldn't advise using this sort of method for constructing SQL (it won't save you from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks at all), the method itself is sound.

Comment: +1 for SQL-injections, we have functions to sanitize the input, but for others that doesn't have it, it was a valid approach.

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried googling for dynamic named parameters with no good results

That's because the capability does not exist.  Think about it - how would the function know what to do if the parameters and their names were not known at compile time?  The closest thing I can think of is using `params` which gives you an *array* of values, but they must all be the same type, and you can still access them by a given name (and index value).

I'd stick with the method you're currently using:

```
.FormatName(new {field = "test", table = "testTable", query = "1 = 1"});
```

That creates an anonymous type with the properties specified, which should work fine with your existing code.  Plus it's only a few extra characters to type.

Also note that `dynamic` doesn't buy you anything here since it's used to access properties *directly* without using reflection.  Since you're using reflection to get the propeties you can just use `object`.

Comment: This is how I am executing the current method. :)

Comment: @NoLifeKing and what's wrong with that method?  You cannot have dynamically named parameters that I know of.

Comment: @NoLifeKing sorry I didn't see that you were using it that way since I didn't scroll right to see the rest of your code.  I'll reformat it for you so it's clearer.